# How to use SQLite SELECT query in python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have created 3 tables like the following

```
----------------Database name is chiledata.sqlite---------------

CREATE TABLE child (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name TEXT
);
----------------Database name is dogdata.sqlite---------------

CREATE TABLE dog (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    dog TEXT
);
----------------Database name is dogChilddata.sqlite---------------

CREATE TABLE child_dog {
    child_id INTEGER,
    dog_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(child_id) REFERENCES child(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(dog_id) REFERENCES dog(id)
};
```

If I use python for make relationship between these tables and execute "SELECT" query how can I connect these 3 tables for this task?

ex:

```
#Import the sqlite3 module
import sqlite3
# Create a connection and cursor to your database
conn = sqlite3.connect('chiledata.sqlite')
c = conn.cursor()
```

So I can connect `chiledata.sqlite` but how can I connect other two database tables (`dogdata.sqlite`, `dogChilddata.sqlite`) to execute `SELECT` query?

Comment: Why did you create 3 separate database files? If the tables are related, you need to store them in *one* database.

Comment: yh..i create 3 separate database files..how can i store them in one database?

Comment: Just open one database connection and create your tables in that one database?

Comment: thank you  Martijn Pieters it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use separate database files if your tables are supposed to be related.

Store all your tables in *one* database file; connect to it, create the tables with that one connection only.

Comment: same  in MySQL and other DBMS ?

Comment: @user3509090: same in *any* relational database.

Comment: @user3509090: cross-database foreign-key relationships are possible in some DBMS products but require extra work. It is not the norm, however.